# Reference to positive solutions of linear systems

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, systems-of-equations, positive-matrices

I would like to ask the community about some references on positive solutions of linear systems. A vector $v=(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ is a positive solution of the linear system $AX=b$ if $Av^T=b$ and $a_i>0$ for all $i$. My question is:

**What are positive solutions of a linear system good for?**

I have seen a lot of interesting mathematics about such solutions and many other features of them (for example, on Roman's *Advanced Linear Algebra*), but I do not know a nice use of these solutions. Any reference on applications of positive solutions of linear systems would be very appreciated.

Comment: Surely in many applications, the variables represent quantities that must be positive, and then a solution with some components negative is meaningless.

Comment: It seems similar to Farkas' lemma. See, Rockafellar: Convex Analysis. Princeton University Press. p. 200.